# Sorting List<T> inside subclass with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, collections, ienumerable

I know I can sort a list doing something like this

```
var result = List<T>.OrderBy(value => value.property);
```

But lets say I have something like this

```
    class Stock
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    class StockList : List<Stock>
    {
        public enum SomeEnum
        {
            SomeOtherValue = 0,
            SomeOtherOtherValue
        }
        //What if I want method like this using LINQ?
        public void Sort(SomeEnum sortBy)
        {
            switch (sortBy) 
            {
                case SomeValue.SomeOtherOtherValue:
                    //Sort one way
                    break;
                case SomeValue.SomeOtherValue:
                    //Sort another
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

`this.OrderBy()` (and I assume the other LINQ extentions) return an OrderedCollection and doesn't seem to affect the original. So I assume I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Note that when you do `List<T>.OrderBY(...)` you aren't sorting the list, you're returning an enumerable that will enumerate over the list in order. i.e. the list isn't effected (as you've found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [List.Sort( )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx). This will do an in-place sort of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
this.Sort(new Comparison<Stock>((x,y) => x.Description.CompareTo(y.Description)));
```